# What happens if I don't update the Google Play Services?

Tags: android, google-play-services

So I'm working in an app I didn't started and there's this "google play services check". In the last version I uploaded (with some minor bug fixes not related with the google play services check), the app asks to update the play services, this doesn't happens in latests versions of the app, only in the last one, regardless the device. Anyone could tell what can be the cause of this? And, what happens if I decide to not update the play services? Does some service stop working?

PS: I would like to remark that NOTHING related to the google play services check has been changed, NOTHING.

Comment: Have you updated your Google Play Services dependencies versions in your last update?

Comment: That's part of the problem, there are devices that can't be updated (don't ask me why, that does not depend on me). Updating the devices fixes the problem obviously, the problem remain with the devices that cannot be updated, that's why I'm asking if is any "real risk" if I just remove the warning of updating the play services.

Comment: In your app's build.gradle, are you using a fixed version of your Google Play Services dependencies? @Doruko

Comment: @ArielCarbonaro yes, I was using 11.4.0, but downgraded to 10.0.0 (I did this because when searching for a solution, I saw some people do this and sometimes the problem fixes, but it's not my case)

Comment: @Doruke That's what I was going to recommend you. About the "real risk" it depends on what API are you using. Pay attention that the dialog can be shown for 3 different scenarios: older version, missing and disabled.

Comment: @ArielCarbonaro As far as I know, the dialog is for "older version" I guess, the thing is that, the play services are installed, and if you go to apps>play services, they won't show the "update" button. They are not missing nor disabled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161310/discussion-between-ariel-carbonaro-and-doruko).